# Program doesn't prompt user for last input, but loops for second book - Data structures

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm learning about data structures. I've written a simple program that asks the user to fill in information on a 3 book purchase. Like name of book, author, cost and pages.

But the program never prompts me for the last question (How many pages). But starts the loop again for the second book.

```
struct bookinfo {
    char title[40];
    char author[25];
    double price;
    int pages;
}; // Header File "bookinfo"

#include "bookinfo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ctr;
    struct bookinfo books[3]; // Array of three structure variables

    // Get the information about each book from the user

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
        gets(books[ctr].title);
        puts("Who is the author? ");
        gets(books[ctr].author);
        puts("How much did the book cost? ");
        scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
        puts("How many pages in the book? ");
        scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
        getchar();  // Clears last newline for the next loop
    }
    // Print a header line and then loop through and print the info
    printf("\n\nHere is the collection of books: \n");
    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("#%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
        printf("\nIt is %d pages and cost $%.2f", books[ctr].pages, books[ctr].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What's your input? And never use `gets`. It is obsolete and dangerous due to its buffer overflow vulnerability.  Also, `scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);` → `scanf(" $%lf", &books[ctr].price);`

Comment: Input > I just use random names and price. It never prompts me for the number of pages though and immediately starts the second loop

Comment: Please update your question to include your exact input. At least one sample set of inputs that cause this problem. Do you input a `$` sign before inputting price?

Comment: Name of book > On innovation, author > John Doe, Price $12.34. If I put a $ sign or not it still starts the second loop > Whats the name of the book.

Comment: No. Not as a comment.  [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42849390/edit) and copy-paste the exact outputs along with the inputs. And did you change `%f` to `%lf` as I suggested?

Comment: What is the name of the book #1?
On Innovation
Who is the author?
John Doe
How much did the book cost?
13.23
How many pages in the book?
What is the name of the book #2?
Who is the author?
Yes I changed it to %1f

Comment: Its `%lf`, not `%1f` (Look carefully)

Comment: `13.23` --> `$13.23`, `%1f` --> `%lf` and your inputs write to post, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `scanf` call fails if you do not exactly type in the $ before the amount. As a result, `scanf` immediately returns, and the second `scanf` reads the input that should have went to the previous `scanf` call.

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't provide the source for the information. According to the man page for scanf(3):

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to process the sequence of input characters.  If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf() returns.  A  "failure"  can  be
>          either of the following: input failure, meaning that input characters were unavailable, or matching failure, meaning that the input was inappropriate (see below).

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried adding the $ it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's strange. I tried your program myself and typing in the $ explicitly allowed it to run normally. Have you tried removing the $ from the first scanf and trying it as you described to Cool Guy?

Comment: Strange because sometimes it works then again it doesn't. I don't understand. I'll check it later. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

Change like this

```
 for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
        gets(books[ctr].title);
        puts("Who is the author? ");
        gets(books[ctr].author);
        puts("How much did the book cost? ");
        scanf("%lf$", &books[ctr].price); //Changed
        puts("How many pages in the book? ");
        scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
        getchar();  // Clears last newline for the next loop
    }
```

[scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) man page

Answer (score 1):

i edited your code by using file processing functions. and it is a good way since it omits all the invalid inputs the user may enter after its answers. like:

```
75467 jhfjkghsj;kfjgklj
```

here is your edited code:

```
struct bookinfo {
    char title[40];
    char author[25];
    double price;
    int pages;
}; // Header File "bookinfo"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ctr;
    struct bookinfo books[3]; // Array of three structure variables

    // Get the information about each book from the user

    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
        gets(books[ctr].title);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        puts("Who is the author? ");
        gets(books[ctr].author);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        puts("How much did the book cost? ");
        scanf(" $%f", &books[ctr].price);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        puts("How many pages in the book? ");
        scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    }
    // Print a header line and then loop through and print the info
    printf("\n\nHere is the collection of books: \n");
    for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("#%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
        printf("\nIt is %d pages and cost $%.2f", books[ctr].pages, books[ctr].price);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I've added the fseek function after every input. this function moves the file pointer to the place you want. here, 0 offset from the end of stdin

Comment: Ok this definitely solved the prompting problem. But I forgot to mention that I get a weird output on price. Here is the output.  

Here is the collection of books:
#1: on innovation by diego sabajo
It is 234 pages and cost $219898507543623520000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00

#2: Effects by john doe
It is 453 pages and cost $2451339502872415300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00

#3: habits by Franklin cofey
It is 453 pages and cost $0.00

Comment: if your numbers are this much big, you must use strings to save them. if you save the numbers using int, the rest of the zeros that were not scaned will be discarded if you use the code above.