# Program outputs astronomical float number after input - C

Tags: c, data-structures, double

After I input floating point numbers e.g. price $12.12, the output is an astronomically large number not even resembling the input. Can somebody please give me an answer. I'm teaching myself programming

```
struct bookInfo {
       char title[40];
       char author[25];
       double price;
       int pages;
       };

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bookinfo.h"

int main(void)
{
   int ctr;
   struct bookInfo books[3]; // Array of three structure variables

// Get the information about each book from the user

   for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
   {
      printf("What is the name of the book #%d?\n", (ctr+1));
      gets(books[ctr].title);
      fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
      puts("Who is the author? ");
      gets(books[ctr].author);
      fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
      puts("How much did the book cost? ");
      scanf(" %1f", &books[ctr].price);
      fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
      puts("How many pages in the book? ");
      scanf(" %d", &books[ctr].pages);
      fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    }
// Print a header line and then loop through and print the info
   printf("\n\nHere is the collection of books: \n");
   for(ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
   {
      printf("#%d: %s by %s", (ctr+1), books[ctr].title, books[ctr].author);
      printf("\nIt is %d pages and cost $%1f", books[ctr].pages,  books[ctr].price);      
      printf("\n\n");
   }
return (0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %1f", &books[ctr].price);` --> `scanf(" $%lf", &books[ctr].price);`

Comment: **Never ever** use `gets`. Is has been removed from the standard as a severe security risc.

Comment: previous [Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849390/program-doesnt-prompt-user-for-last-input-but-loops-for-second-book-data-str) again.

Comment: Ok. Yes I read about it.  But as of this moment I haven't learned the other methods to output strings. So could gets be the problem?

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall`. It would have [probably] flagged the `scanf` [that BLUEPIXY spotted] at compile time. And, replace (e.g.) `gets(books[ctr].title)` with `fgets(books[ctr].title,sizeof(books[ctr].title),stdin)` et. al. But, you'll also need to manually strip a newline [one difference between `gets` and `fgets`]. I'd create a function that looks like `fgets`, calls `fgets`, but strips newline before returning

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Right. But the last time was for the program not prompting. This was solved with the fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END); solved that problem. BTW the $ dollar sign didn't fix the problem

Comment: `1` --> `l` and What did you actually enter? `$12.12`? or just `12.12` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Damn me! I entered a 1

Comment: In the case of `$12.12`, `$` is required.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you! It solved the prolem.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why is the dollar sign needed? Say for instance I was not entering a price but just a division between 2 numbers.

Comment: `%lf` does not read `$`, so if you enter a number with `$`, you need to let it skip it as a format.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Understood thank you!